# android have dialog int extendes class with ListFragment

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

i have `ReceiveListFragment` class extends `ListFragment` and i want to have `Dialog` but i get error and i cant resolve problem.

```
public static class CDialog extends DialogFragment {
        public AddNoteDialogFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            getDialog().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vdialog,
                    container);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
            dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            return dialog;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE POST 1:**

```
use this class:
Error:(196, 15) java: no suitable method found for show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,java.lang.String)
    method android.app.DialogFragment.show(android.app.FragmentTransaction,java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (actual argument android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.app.FragmentTransaction by method invocation conversion)
    method android.app.DialogFragment.show(android.app.FragmentManager,java.lang.String) is not applicable
      (actual argument android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.app.FragmentManager by method invocation conversion)
```

ScreenShot:
[image]

**UPDATE POST 2:**
And for this below function i get this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Function:

```
public Boolean eDialog(){
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which){
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                        System.exit(1);
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(G.context);

        builder.setMessage("Are you Exit?").setPositiveButton("yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("no", dialogClickListener).show();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What kind of error? you should add false as third parameter for the inflater `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vdialog,
                    container, false);`

Comment: @blackbelt Thanks sir.i'm update post with screenshot and Error.

Comment: the problem is that you are mixing imports from the support library and the native. You have to be consistent. All the imports have to be either the native  or from the support library

Comment: @blackbelt i'm update post again.

Comment: @blackbelt no thats not null. i'm checked it

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DFragment extends DialogFragment {
    //...
};

public class AccidentDetailsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    //...
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    DFragment dialog = DFragment.newInstance("Test");
    dialog.show(fm, "ss");
```